# Single power feed for two lamps plus a spark core microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, ac, relay

I'm starting a project where I want to control two lamps which are currently powered from mains electricity using a Wifi-capable microcontroller (spark core) and a relay.

I want the result to be as neat as possible so I wanted to use only one source of power for the whole arrangement, this would mean wiring up the two lamps together and also taking a 5 volt feed from that same power source.

I'm coming at this from the programming world, so have a little microcontroller experience but I'm not sure how I would wire up the rest of the arrangement, can anyone illustrate how I might achieve this?

Comment: You have all the right parts, a micro-controller, relays, lamps. The micro-controller digital outputs drive the relays, the bulbs are connected though the relay contacts to your mains supply, and the micro-controller is powered from a PSU also connected to the mains what more do you need?

Comment: I had thought it was more complicated than that, but yes, I think you're right.

Comment: The only thing I think you need to check is the voltage and current required to operate the relays (typically several volts and a couple hundred mA), against the current available from the micro outputs (typically a few mA) at a few volts - if you use solid state relays (SSR's),  a direct connection may be possible; else you may need an external interface buffer to boost the micro signal and provide the required relay drive.